# How to change colors in Kivy

Tags: python, colors, kivy

I need to adjust the color of my kivy app in Python 
This is what i have now
Can someone help me out?

```
 <MainScreen>:
        name: "main"
            Color:
                rgba: self.r,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
<MainScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, .3, .8, .5
        Rectangle:
            size: root.size
```

Replace this `1, .3, .8, .5` with the color in this format `255/255, 184/255, 255/255, 255/255`. 
The last one is the alpha.
If you don't need alpha, you need to use `rgb` and remove the last value.
Thank you.

Comment: Thank you a lot, you just save the day :)

Comment: @LvdB You can also check mark the checkmark and upvote the answer if you like.